# Decreasing integers on the blackboard

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

There are $n\geq 2$ copies of an integer $k>0$ written on the blackboard. A *move* consists of choosing an integer $m>0$ on the blackboard, and replacing it as well as one other integer on the blackboard (you can choose which one) by the integer $m-1$.

For example, if you have numbers $(3,0,1)$ on the blackboard, a move can change them to $(2,2,1)$ or $(2,0,2)$ or $(3,0,0)$ or $(0,0,0)$.

What is the maximum possible number $f(n,k)$ of moves you can perform? An asymptotic answer would be good enough (I think it could be $O(kn^2)$).

Comment: A copy is a replica of something. So there are at least 3 of the same object? Also, define "blackboard". Is it a set?

Comment: @DonLarynx Really, just think of it as a blackboard. You write down the number $k$ a total of $n$ times. That's really all. Please let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: I repeat the question that was *ignored*....A copy is a replica of something. So there are at least 3 of the same object?

Comment: There are $n≥2$ copies of an integer...so there are 3 of the same integer? That's really all.

Comment: @DonLarynx You first choose integers $n\geq 2$ and $k>0$. Say you choose $n=7$ and $k=5$. Then you write down the number $5$ a total of seven times on the blackboard.

Comment: @PJMiller In your example, a move could also change the set to (0,0,0), yes?  Just to be complete...

Comment: We can always make at least $k(n-1)$ steps.

Denote by $M(i,j)$ the move consisting in replacing integers number
$i$ and $j$ by the value formerly located at $j$, minus one.

Starting from the initial position $(k,k,k,k,\ldots ,k)$, and applying
successively $M(1,2),M(2,3),M(3,4), \ldots ,M(n-1,n)$, we reach
$(k-1,k-1,k-1,k-1,\ldots ,k-1)$ in $n-1$ steps.

Iterating this, we eventually reach $(0,0,\ldots,0)$ in $k(n-1)$ steps.

Comment: The maximal number of moves $f(n,k)\le n(2^k-1)$. Proof. For each non-negative number $m$ define its weight $w(m)=2^m-1$. Then $w(m)+w(0)>2w(m-1)$ for each $m\ge 1$. Therefore at each move the total weight of the numbers on the blackboard is decreasing. Hence the maximal number of moves $f(n,k)$ is not greater than the initial total weight $n(2^k-1)$.

Comment: Maybe the best strategy is always choose as the decreasing number $m$ the minimal non-zero number provided there are zeros on the blackboard and the number $a_i\ge a_j$ with $i\not=j$, where $a_j$ is a minimal number provided there are zeros on the blackboard.  The other number to be changed to $m-1$ should be, of course, $a_j$ .  A bounty seeker can write a simple program realizing this  strategy and thus calculate the lower bounds for $f(n,k)$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky: I didn't get about the weight of m and how they are related to the proof. Can you please explain me?

Comment: @PhaniRaj I used a standard method of so called semiinvariants.

Comment: Suppose that we have a system $\mathcal S$ (in our case the collection of the numbers on the blackboard) with the set $S$ of its possible states, the set $O$ of operations changing the states of the system $\mathcal S$ and we wish to prove that for each state $s\in S$ of the system $\mathcal S$ there exists a number $N=N(s)$ (depending on $s$) such that when we consecutively apply to $s$ an arbitrary sequence $\{o_1,o_2,\dots,o_N\}$ of length $N$ of operations from $O$, we obtain a stable state $s_0$ (that is such a state that $o(s_0)=s_0$ for each operation $o\in O$.

Comment: This will be done if we define a so-called semiinvariant that is a function $W$ from $S$ to the set of *nonnegative* integers such that $W(s)<W(o(s))$ for any unstable state $t\in S$ and any operation $o\in O$  (and we shall have a bound $N(s)\le W(s)$). In our case we have that $W(s)$ of the collection $s=(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is equal to the sum $\sum_{i=1}^nw(a_i)\equiv \sum_{i=1}^n (2^{a_i}-1)$. The inequality $w(m)+w(0)>2w(m-1)$ assures that $W(s)<W(o(s))$ for any non-zero state $s$ and any move $o$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thanks for the explanation. I want to read more about this technique, but unfortunately i couldn't get good material(like lecture notes or similar) when i searched in google. So can you please give me some references about this. It will be very helpful.

Comment: @PhaniRaj There is a problem with the references. I was taught this technique when I was trained for school math competitions and “semiinvariants” is my translation of “полуинварианты” from Russian.  But it seems that in English this technique has other name because I found no relevant English references by “semiinvariant” or “halfinvariant” query.

Comment: @PhaniRaj I found some links to pages in Russian containing the relevant school problems: http://www.problems.ru/view_by_subject_new.php?parent=614 http://school-collection.edu.ru/catalog/rubr/1040fa23-ac04-b94b-4a41-bd93fbf0d55a/25465/ http://diductio.ru/course/1474/ Is this OK for you or we should try to find some English resources?

Comment: @AlexRavsky thanks I could translate to english using google. But I want to know about the method(why and how it works?) rather than just doing problems. Also can you say in which specific area of maths do we come across these?

Comment: @PhaniRaj Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12079/semiinvariants).

Comment: @AlexRavsky, the term "monovariant" is sometimes used, but it is a recent thing (last 10-15 years) and only in the setting of competitions.  I have never seen it in published mathematics, where one would say something like "decreasing function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Alex noted, the following proves the local optimality of his and @Yong's algorithm in some measure. In fact the measure I use cannot prove global optimality on general states, since the score for $(5,5,1,0,0)$ is $56$ while that for $(5,4,4,4,4)$ is $58$. In two optimal steps each, the sequences reach $(5,4,4,0,0)$ and $(5,4,4,2,2)$ respectively, where it's easy to see that the second is at least two steps better.

```
5,4,4,4,4    5,5,1,0,0
5,4,4,3,3    5,4,4,1,0
5,4,4,2,2    5,4,4,0,0
```

Let $T$ be $k+1$. $a_i$'s. First observation, if we are picking $i$ and $j$, then we should always replace them by the bigger of $a_i-1$ and $a_j-1$. Write down the numbers in decreasing order and read them as an $(T+1)$ base expansion so that $a_i$ corresponds to $a_i(T+1)^i$. So then $j>i$.

Now after the operation, the $a_j-1$ that replaces $a_i$ moves to $j-1\ge i$, and everything in between is shifted to the right. Then the operation to be done is subtract $\delta  \ge (T+1)^j - T\times(T+1)^k >0 $. Note that by construction, either $a_j-1 \ge a_i$ or $a_j = a_i$.

So first of all, the base $(T+1)$ number decreases. We can see what makes this decrease the smallest. We have the bounds 
$$(T+1)^{j-1} \leq \delta \le (T+1)^j$$

So for a given $i$, $j$ should be as low as possible.

If $a_i =0$, this means $j$ should be the smallest such that $a_j>0$, and then $i$ does not matter.

Otherwise, $j = i+1$, and then the same bounds tell us that $i$ should be as low as possible.

Some upper bounds are below.

---

First, starting from any state of the blackboard, we can make only finitely many moves. To see this, first note that in any move, we cannot increase the maximum. Now, we induct on number of terms on the board.

Note that once a maximal term occurs as $i$ or $j$ in a move $M(i,j)$ as in Ewan's comment and answer, it cannot get back to its original value again, since if $T$ is the maximum  value, then every replacement is with at most $T-1$. Now, it is enough to show that the maximum has to decrease in a finite number of moves. Assume on the contrary that there is an infinite sequence of moves that preserves the maximum. Then, some maximal value not be used in a move at all. But by induction, there are only finitely many possible moves that can be made on the rest of the terms.

This also tells us that there cannot be any periodic set of states, so that the total possible number of states ($-1$) is an upper bound. The number of states is the number of non-increasing sequences of length $n$ where every term is $\le k$. This is given by $\binom{k+n}{k}-1$. A slightly better upper bound is below.

Now, suppose that for a multiset of size $n$, with maximum $T$, the maximum number of moves possible (over all such multisets) is $f(T,n)$. Obviously, $$f(T,2 ) = T$$. By the same argument as above, 
$$f(T,n+1) \le f(T,n)+f(T-1,n) +1 $$
By induction, $f(T,n) \le \binom{T+n-1}{T} - 1 \le (T+1)^n-1$ but this seems to have room for improvement.

@AlexRavsky's upper bound is much better for a fixed $k$, while this is better for a fixed $n$.

Here are some actual values for the $k,n$ defined in the problem, and the best of the two upper bounds above, $\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}-1$ and $n(2^k-1)$:

```
k\n|   2   3   4   5   6   7   8          k\n|   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  
---+-----------------------------         ---+-----------------------------
 1 |   1   2   3   4   5   6   7           1 |   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
 2 |   2   5   8  11  14  17  20           2 |   2   5   9  14  18  21  24
 3 |   3   9  16  23  30  37  44     <     3 |   3   9  19  34  42  49  56
 4 |   4  14  28  43  58  73  88     =     4 |   4  14  34  69  90 105 120
 5 |   5  20  45  75 106 137               5 |   5  20  55 125 186 217 
 6 |   6  27  68 124 186                   6 |   6  27  83 209 378 
 7 |   7  35  98 196                       7 |   7  35 119 329
```

Comment: It seems for me that, unfortunately, we have no proof of the optimality of this greedy algorithm. The problem is that you have proved its local, but not global optimality with respect to the decreasing of the weight (which in your case is equal to the $(T+1)$-base expansion) of the collection of the numbers. In particular it means that there is possible a situation when a move which slightly decreases the weight, makes the position so bad that every possible next move strongly decreases the weight.

Answer (score 6):

That's another answer that comes from all ideas in other answers.

Consider a blackboard $B$ with $n$ numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n$, such that $a_i\le a_{i+1}$.

Let $W$ the weight function defined by 
$$W(B)=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^{i-1}\binom{a_i}{k} $$

Let's make a move in $B$. So we choose $1\le i\le n$, and $1\le j\le n$ (with $j\neq i$), and transform $a_i$ (and $a_j$) into $a_{i}-1$ to obtain the blackboard $B'$ with $n$ value $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n$ ($b_i\le b_{i+1}$ : We order the values again)

- if $a_j\ge a_i$, then both value are reduced. By trivial induction, $b_i\le a_i$ (and for some $i>1$, we have $b_i<a_i$) and $W(B')<W(B)$.
- if $a_j<a_i$, we can consider (without loss of generality) that $a_i>a_{i-1}$. Hence $B'$ will be such that :

  - for $i< k\le n$ : $b_k=a_k$
  - $b_{i-1}=b_i=a_i-1$ (that's former $a_i$ and $a_j$)
  - for $j\le k<i-1$ : $b_k=a_{k+1}$ (we just move former $a_j$ from index $j$ to index $i-1$)
  - for $k<j$ : $b_k=a_k$

Hence :

$$W(B)-W(B')=\sum_{k=j}^{i}\sum_{l=1}^{k-1}\binom{a_k}{l}-\binom{b_k}{l}$$
For $k=i$, we have :
$$\left(\sum_{l=1}^{i-1}\binom{a_i}{l}-\binom{a_i-1}{l}\right)=\sum_{l=1}^{i-1}\binom{a_i-1}{l-1}=1+\sum_{l=1}^{i-2}\binom{b_{i-1}}{l}$$

Hence (I let the attentive reader understand the cancellations that come from $b_k=a_{k+1}$) $$W(B)-W(B')=1+\sum_{l=1}^{j-1}\binom{a_j}{l}+\sum_{k=j+1}^{i-1}\binom{a_k}{k-1}>0$$

Note that now, if you take $j=1$ and $a_i$ ($i>1$) the smallest $a_k>0$, you will have

$$W(B)-W(B')=1$$

So $W(B)$ is the maximum number of moves that you can play into $B$.

$$f(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i)\binom{k}{i} $$

Answer (score 4):

I can prove an exact answer for $n=3$ which I can extend to an algorithm for $n\geq 4$.
The number of steps seems to correspond to ronno's table.

**[1] Best Algorithm for $n=3$**
Let $n=3$ and we start with $(k,k,k)$.
Consider the algorithm:
A series of $M(1,2): (k,k,k)\to (0,0,k)$.
$M(3,2): (0,0,k)\to (0,k-1,k-1)$
A series of $M(1,2): (0,k-1,k-1)\to (0,0,k-1)$.
$M(3,2): (0,0,k-1)\to (0,k-2,k-2)$
$\dots$

This will give me $\dfrac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}-1=\dfrac{k^2+3k}{2}$ moves.

I claim that it is the maximum via induction.
Clearly this is true for $k=0$.
Now consider $(k+1,k+1,k+1)$.
The algorithm tells me that $\dfrac{(k+1)^2+3(k+1)}{2}=\dfrac{k^2+5k+4}{2}$ is a lower bound.

The first move must give me $(k,k,k+1)$.
If I next make it $(k,k,k)$, the maximum I can get is $2+\dfrac{k^2+3k}{2}=\dfrac{k^2+3k+4}{2}<\dfrac{k^2+5k+4}{2}$.
Hence I can only possibly beat the lower bound by making my next move $(k-1,k-1,k)$.
It is clear that using this argument, I have to reach $(0,0,k+1)$.
For otherwise on the $r+1$-th step I will get $(k-r,k-r,k+1)\to (k-r,k,k)$.
Then the maximum moves is $r+1+\dfrac{k^2+3k}{2}=\dfrac{k^2+3k+2+2r}{2}$, which is always $\leq \dfrac{k^2+5k+4}{2}$ since $r\leq k+1$.

**[2] Extending to $n \geq 4$**
The most "natural" generalization of this algorithm for $n\geq 4$ is to:
(1) Reduce to $(0,0,0,k,\dots,k)$ via $n=3$ algorithm.
(2) $(0,0,0,k,\dots,k)\to (0,0,k-1,k-1,\dots,k)$.
(3) $(0,0,k-1,k-1,\dots,k)\to (0,k-2,k-2,k-1,\dots,k)$.
(4) Repeat $n=3$ algorithm on $(0,k-2,k-2)$.
(5) Repeat procedure. For instance the next "start" would be $(0,k-3,k-3,k-2,\dots,k)$.

It should be possible to derive a formula, but I have no idea how to do it in a short way.

**Edit 1**: The first few formulas are
$n=3: \dfrac{k(k+3)}{2}$, $n=4: \dfrac{k(k^2 + 3 k + 14)}{6}$, $n=5: \dfrac{k(k^3+2k^2+23k+70)}{24}$.

In general the algorithm seems to give about $O(k^{n-1})$.

The computation is using:
$$g(n,k)=k+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} g(n-1,i)$$
$$f(n,k)=\sum_{i=2}^{n} g(i,k)$$
with initial condition $g(2,k)=k$, where $f(n,k)$ is the solution we want.
$g(n,k)$ is the number of steps for $(0,0,\dots,0,k)$.

Comment: It seems that your strategy coincides with the described in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602166/decreasing-integers-on-the-blackboard#comment1290272_602166) comment. So you can wrote the program calculating the respective values for small $n$ and $k$ and then try to find a general formula for them. Maybe I myself shall wrote this program but I am still hoping to find a more simple way to derive the formula.

Comment: @ronno I did the computation for $n=2$ to $n=5$ and the values correspond exactly to your table.  
AlexRavsky This seems to be related to sum of consecutive powers and I found some guides [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/sumsofpowers.html). But looking at the series it seems like quite a mess.

Comment: It seems that the sum formulas imply $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+g(n-1,k)$ and $g(n,k)=g(n,k-1)+g(n-1,k-1)+1$.

Comment: Moreover, it seems then $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+f(n,k-1)-f(n-2,k-1)+1$.

Comment: From the recurrence for $f$, a lower bound of $\Omega(k^{n-1})$ seems difficult, since asymptotically $k^{n-1} \gg k^{n-2}$.

Comment: Conjecture. It seems that $g(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{k \choose i}$, where ${k \choose i}=k(k-1)\dots (k-i+1)/i!$

Comment: @AlexRavsky My apologies, it should be added till $n$. Then we get $f(3,k)=g(3,k)+g(2,k)=k+(k^2+k)/2=(k^2+3k)/2$.

Comment: Then it seems that the sum formulas imply $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+g(n,k)$ and the other two formulas still are $g(n,k)=g(n,k-1)+g(n-1,k-1)+1$
and $f(n,k)=f(n-1,k)+f(n,k-1)-f(n-2,k-1)+1$.

Comment: At last, I have a conjecture for the formula $f(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i){k \choose i}$, where ${k \choose i}=k(k-1)\dots (k-i+1)/i!$

Comment: Your [link](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~erowland/sumsofpowers.html) suggests that there may be no more simple expression for $f(n.k)$, so we have to asymptotically estimate this expression. And these asymptotics may be different for the cases 1:$n=const, k\to\infty$, 2:$k=const, n\to\infty$ and 3: $n=k\to\infty$. But this may be not our proper problem, because we have to do our combinatorial par and we may forward the asymptotic estimation of the proved formula to other specialists, for instance, by asking a question at MSE. :-)

Comment: It seems that in Case 1 we have an asymptotic $f(n,k)=k^{n-1}/(n-1)!+O(k^{n-2})$, in Case 3 we have an *equality* $f(n,k)=n2^{n-1}+n$, and in Case 2 we have an *equality* $f(n,k)=2^{k-1}(2n-k)-n$, because our ${k \choose i}=0$ when $k<i$. In fact, the last equality should hold for each $n\ge k+1$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky $f(n,k)=k^{n-1}/(n-1)! + O(k^{n-2})$ seems correct to me. I don't quite see how you computed cases 2 and 3 though.

Comment: I used a formula $\sum_{i=0}^{n}i{n \choose i}=n2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I see, thanks for all your clarifications! =D

Answer (score 3):

I made a small program to compute the value $f(n,k)$ for small $n$ and  $k$.

$$\begin{array}{l|cc}
k^\mbox{$\;\;n$}& 2& 3& 4 & 5& 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\
\hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
2 & 2 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 14 & 17 & 20 & 23 & 26 & 29 \\
3 & 3 & 9 & 16 & 23 & 30 & 37 & 44 & 51 & 58 & 65 \\
4 & 4 & 14 & 28 & 43 & 58 & 73 & 88 & 103 & 118 & 133 \\
5 & 5 & 20 & 45 & 75 & 106 & 137 & 168 & 199 & 230 & 261 \\
6 & 6 & 27 & 68 & 124 & 186 & 249 & 312 & 375 & 438 & 501 \\
7 & 7 & 35 & 98 & 196 & 315 & 441 & 568 & 695 & 822 & 949 \\
8 & 8 & 44 & 136 & 298 & 516 & 762 & 1016 & 1271 & 1526 & 1781 \\
9 & 9 & 54 & 183 & 438 & 819 & 1284 & 1785 & 2295 & 2806 & 3317 \\
10 & 10 & 65 & 240 & 625 & 1262 & 2109 & 3076 & 4088 & 5110 & 6133 \\
11 & 11 & 77 & 308 & 869 & 1892 & 3377 & 5192 & 7172\\
\end{array}
$$

It seems that values from ronno are good. Note that it seems that for $n\ge k$, $f(n+1,k)=f(n,k)+2^k-1$

And $f(n,n)$ seems to be [A058877](https://oeis.org/A058877) = $n(2^{(n-1)}-1)$

---

Here is the program I made (python 3.3). It could be improved ! Because I used recursive calls to write it quickly, but it's not that good in python.

```
import functools
import sys

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def val(t) :
    res=[]
    pi= -1 
    for i in range(len(t)) :
        if t[i]>0 and t[i] != pi :
            pj= -1
            for j in range(len(t)) :
                if j != i and t[j] != pj :
                    newt=list(t)
                    newt[i]-=1
                    newt[j]=newt[i]
                    newt.sort()
                    res.append(val(tuple(newt)))
                    pj=t[j]
        pi=t[i]
    return(0 if res==[] else 1+max(res)) 


def vval(k,n) :
    return(val((k,)*n))

def main(m) :
    sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
    for k in range(1,m) :
        print(k,end=" ")
        for n in range(2,m) :
            print("&",vval(k,n), end=" ")
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print("\\\\")

main(12)
```

Comment: I happened to notice that going down columns, when $n=3$ the first difference (i.e, $5-2,9-5,14-9,\ldots$) is $3,4,5,\ldots$, while for $n=4$, the first difference is $5,8,12,17,\ldots$ but the *second* difference is $3,4,5,\ldots$.  For $n=5$, the first difference is $7,12,20,32,49\ldots$, the second difference is $5,8,12,17,\ldots$, and the *third* difference is $3,4,5,\ldots$.  This is pure observation, though, without proof or even checking all the numbers.

Comment: Just to summarize (and simplify) the observation of my previous comment, the *first* difference for column $n$ appears to be the *second* difference for column $n+1$.

Comment: Xoff: Just to be clear, what are the values that you're showing in your table? Are they $f(n,k)$? If so, I would appreciate if you could say a bit about how you wrote the program (i.e. what your program structure looks like), in case I want to reproduce it myself. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see my observation agrees with **Edit 1** in Yong Hao Ng's answer.

Comment: @PJMiller yes it's $f(n,k)$. I made my program available in the answer for you.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes it seems that :
$$f(n+1,k+1)=f(n+1,k)+f(n,k)+n $$

Comment: @Xoff, ah yes.  I also see that Alex Ravsky, in the comments to Ng's answer, has conjectured that  $$f(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(n-i){k\choose i}$$ which I think agrees with all this.